# How to test Flux of Fluxes like Flux<Flux<Object>>

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have this interface:

```kotlin
interface PageRepository {
  fun findAll(): Flux<Flux<Page>>
}
```

And I want to test its implementation but I'm getting:
`java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(FluxIterable)" failed (expected value: FluxIterable; actual value: UnicastProcessor)`

In the test I'm using `expectNext()`:

```kotlin
 repository
      .findAll()
      .test()
      .expectSubscription()
      .expectNext(listOf(page(PATH_1), page(PATH_2)).toFlux())
      .expectNext(listOf(page(PATH_3), page(PATH_4)).toFlux())
      .expectNext(listOf(page(PATH_5)).toFlux())
      .verifyComplete()
```

What I'm missing

Answer (score 4):

expectNext use equals that's why this fail even if both flux contains the same data they are not the same.

What you could do is the following:

```kotlin
repository().findAll()
        .test()
        .expectSubscription()
        .assertNext {
            it.test()
                    .expectNext(page(PATH_1), page(PATH_2))
                    .verifyComplete()
        }.assertNext {
            it.test()
                    .expectNext(page(PATH_3), page(PATH_4))
                    .verifyComplete()
        }.assertNext {
            it.test()
                    .expectNext(page(PATH_5))
                    .verifyComplete()
        }.verifyComplete()
```

I don't know if there is a better option but this should work.